# How to encrypt Connectionstring written in web.config from codebehind?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-config

I need to encrypt connectionstring and some appsettings keys value in web.config from code behind.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check these url - use  aspnet_regiis.exe
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection.aspx

Answer (score 2):

try  this

```
private void ProtectSection(string sectionName,
                                   string provider)
    {
        Configuration config =
            WebConfigurationManager.
                OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);

        ConfigurationSection section =
                     config.GetSection(sectionName);

        if (section != null &&
                  !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
            config.Save();
        }
    }
```